Running npm run dev shows an error called 'The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed.'
I'm learning how to create apps on Shopify and need some help.
Whenever I run, npm run dev and click any key, it shows this even though I'm already logged in to Shopify.
npm run dev

> dev
> shopify app dev



To run this command, log in to Shopify.
 Press any key to open the login page on your browser
╭─ error ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                               │
│  The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed.       │
│                                                               │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

And redirect me to a page URL: http://127.0.0.1:3456/?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The%20requested%20scope%20is%20invalid%2C%20unknown%2C%20or%20malformed.&state=a0314fb1a276fd7dbffb5ec6e35d8ff2137c1c666f68ea953143f63a37eb
that says:
Something went wrong!
There was an issue while trying to authenticate.
Return to your terminal and try running the previous command again.
Here's a screen recording on how to replicate the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zx7ee0YUHMwkoxHTdYeXbsuUDx9_C8Mo/view?usp=sharing

same issue here. our project stopped running locally all of a sudden. It may be an issue with shopify servers itself.

It seems it was an issue on Shopify's end. I tried running the npm run dev again, and it works now.

It looks like the new version (v3.61.0) is broken somewhere in the auth-flow. Simply install a previous version, e.g. 3.60.1, and it should work for the moment:
npm install -g @shopify/cli@3.60.1


New version (v3.61.0) is broken.
1 step brew uninstall shopify-cli
2 step rm -rf ~/.shopify-app-cli/
3 step npm install -g @shopify/cli@3.59.1




I had several almost identical errors and it worked for me to change the port shopify theme dev --store theme.myshopify.com --port=4000
